# Multiple objective allocation function

Tags: r, linear-model, optimization

I have an allocation problem where, for a given good, I have buyer $i$ willing to buy up to quantity $b_{s,i}$ and seller $j$ willing to sell up to quantity $s_{s,i}$. There are $N$ buyers and $M$ sellers. I have to allocate the good among the buyers and sellers, where I choose amounts $b_i$ and $s_i$ that are bought and sold. My objective functions are:

1. I maximize the amount of good bought + amount of good sold:
   $L = \sum_{i=1}^N b_i + \sum_{j=1}^M s_j$
2. I minimize the sum of the residuals: $R = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(b_{s,i} - b_i)}{b_{s,i}} + \sum_{j=1}^M \frac{(s_{s,j} - s_jj)}{s_{s,j}}$
3. I maximize the number of buys/sells where the residual is zero: $F = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{1}_{b_i=b_{s,i}} + \sum_{j=1}^M \mathbf{1}_{s_j=s_{s,j}}$

Maximizing $L$ takes priority. Minimizing $R$ and maximizing $F$ have equal priority. These are my constraints:

a. $\sum_{i=1}^N b_i=\sum_{j=1}^M s_j$

b. $0 \le b_i \le b_{s,j}$

c. $0 \le s_i \le s_{s,j}$

I'm contemplating two methods right now. The first one is the [lexicographic preference method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) because I prefer optimizing 1. over 2. and 3. The second one is just regular linear programming, where I weight 2. and 3. so that they cannot overpower 1.

Which one would you use, or would you use another method?